# imfilter function with Matlab Coder?

Tags: matlab, matlab-coder

When I used `imfilter()` function with Matlab coder , it appears error

```
 Expected input number 1, A to be one of theses types: nummeric,logical. Instead its type was embedded.fi
```

How can I fix this problems?

Comment: Do you have image processing toolbox?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in matrix A (*Showing its class attributes or how you create it would certainly help*). A is a `fi` - fixed numeric object (read about [embedded.fi](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/fixedpoint/ref/embedded.fi-class.html) class), which you can transform to `numeric, logical` using its `Data properties`.

Hope this is helpful.